# Getting two descriptions of a variety to agree

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $\zeta$ is a 3rd root of 1 in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $G=\mathbb{Z}/3$ act on $\mathbb{C}^2$ by multiplication on both factors by $\zeta$: $\zeta \cdot (x,y) = (\zeta x,\zeta y)$. A nice but probably irrelevant observation is that this action of $G$ is not in $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. If we take the geometric quotient $X:=\mathbb{C}^2/G$, the invariant polynomials $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^G$ are generated by polynomials $A=x^3,B=x^2y,C=xy^2,D=y^3$ and they satisfy the relations $AC=B^2, BD=C^2, AD=BC$.

One might notice that these are the same equations found on the Wikipedia page for the twisted cubic but just in affine space instead (so $X$ is an affine cone over the twisted the cubic). So here, we have two ways to describe $X$; as a quotient singularity or as a variety in $\mathbb{C}^4$ (which famously, is not a complete intersection).

But now, suppose I replace $\mathbb{C}$ with some other field, say $\mathbb{F}_7$; note that $2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ so this field contains a 3rd root of 1. If I let $\mathbb{Z}/3$ act on $\mathbb{F}^2_7$ by multiplication by 2 on both factors and take the geometric quotient, I think there are 9 orbit classes so 9 points in the geometric quotient. On the other hand, if I count solutions to the same 3 equations in 4 variables as before but now over $\mathbb{F}_7$, there are a lot more than 9 points. And there are probably even more if I counted solutions in a field extension.

So my **question:** What, if any, is the "correct" way take a quotient or to count the points in the geometric quotient so that the result describes the same algebraic variety as the 3 equations in 4 variables? It would be nice if the way to do it still works if we then considered the same equations in a field extension of the base field. This question probably reveals that I'm not well-versed in algebraic geometry so I'd appreciate more "low-level" explanations if possible.

By the way, I don't know if "geometric quotient" is the correct terminology. Please correct me if it's not.

Comment: My understanding is that the quotient of an affine variety $\operatorname{Spec} R$ by a finite group $G$ can always be obtained as $\operatorname{Spec} R^G$, even over $\mathbb Z$. The main issue is that once you start trying to deal with non-finite groups, it's pretty hard to do anything "low-level."

Comment: As to why the point count doesn't work out (assuming all of your computations are correct), my guess is that there might be some "correct way of counting" that needs to be used (like how we count intersection points with multiplicity, but now we need to take into account points with non-trivial stabilizers), but I can't say anything for sure.